# Find out why postgres pod keeps restarting

Tags: kubernetes

I have a postgres database running in my cluster based off the `bitnami/postgres` helm chart.

However, looking at the pod, which is 18 days old, it has restarted 39 times in that time period.

Checking the previous logs, I see the following:

```
postgresql 09:06:19.75
postgresql 09:06:19.84 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 09:06:19.86 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
postgresql 09:06:19.88 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
postgresql 09:06:19.90
postgresql 09:06:20.30 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 09:06:20.36 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 09:06:20.38 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 09:06:20.49 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 09:06:30.04 INFO  ==> Cleaning stale /bitnami/postgresql/data/postmaster.pid file
postgresql 09:06:30.17 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
postgresql 09:06:30.18 INFO  ==> Generating local authentication configuration
postgresql 09:06:30.28 INFO  ==> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
postgresql 09:06:30.48 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
postgresql 09:06:30.69 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
postgresql 09:06:30.94 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
postgresql 09:06:30.96 INFO  ==> Enabling remote connections
postgresql 09:06:31.06 INFO  ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **

postgresql 09:06:31.18 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
2021-03-27 09:06:31.811 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
2021-03-27 09:06:31.813 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-03-27 09:06:31.813 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-03-27 09:06:32.015 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-03-27 09:06:32.285 GMT [97] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-03-26 19:29:14 GMT
2021-03-27 09:06:33.428 GMT [103] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-03-27 09:06:34.350 GMT [97] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2021-03-27 09:06:34.433 GMT [97] LOG:  redo starts at 0/32A7EE0
2021-03-27 09:06:34.433 GMT [97] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/32A7FC0: wanted 24, got 0
2021-03-27 09:06:34.434 GMT [97] LOG:  redo done at 0/32A7F88
2021-03-27 09:06:34.782 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

As you can see from the log, nothing is particularly wrong.  In fact this log is essentially identical to the logs of the current container.  It does say that the database was interrupted, but I'm not sure why it would be interrupted.

Inspecting the pod shows no events as to why it was restarted.

So why is the pod restarting fairly frequently?

### Edit

describe pod shows exit code 255.

The liveness and rediness probes are default for the helm chart, and are described below:

```
Liveness:   exec [/bin/sh -c exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
Readiness:  exec [/bin/sh -c -e exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
```

[ -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized ]
] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6

Comment: It will show an ExitCode in `kubectl describe pod` and that is almost certainly 139 as it was OOMKilled -- unless you have a `livenessCheck:` which complicates matters

Comment: @mdaniel edited my post.  Exit code was 255 and the liveness/rediness probes are default for the chart.  Details of probes in my post.